# Where can I find the Xenial source, and instructions on building it into an ISO? (custom install CD for Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: iso, live-cd, source-code, custom-distributions, 16.04

I followed [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) and managed to build a distro:

However it only boots with VirtualBox, and this guide is hopelessly out of date. Searching around the net, I found this handy tutorial on
[Legacy Bios, UEFI and SecureBoot ready Ubuntu Live image customization](https://linuxconfig.org/legacy-bios-uefi-and-secureboot-ready-ubuntu-live-image-customization)

Now I managed to get something sort of working. There are still problems and the guide is not complete.

However the question still remains- where can I find this info?

Where is the source repository for Ubuntu with the build guide?

Comment: Use Rinzwind's answer with the 16.04 beta ISOs.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/ubuntu-minimal

Hope it helps, thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/541455)

Comment: Noted David, will take care from now on. Regards

Comment: Never mind. My canned comment from review wasn't very accurate in this case anyway. The question asked for an online resource, so a link is theoretically fine as an answer. Though additionally the question asks for instructions on how to use that resource, which in turn makes a link-only answer "low quality" which means it's likely to be deleted.

Comment: No worries David, it's a learning for me too, glad you mentored. Regards